# How to see data inside Sqlite database created by Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a `SQLite` database with `Android` but I am having problems trying to check the information that I have stored on it.

I have created a `DBHelper` class like follows:

```
public class AnimalsSqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE Animals (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, numberAnimal INTEGER)";

    public AnimalsSqliteHelper(Context context, String name,
                               SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int vOld, int vNew) {
    }
}
```

And I insert data in other class like follows:

```
//Create an instance of a writable database
AnimalsSqliteHelper usdbh = new AnimalsSqliteHelper(getContext(), "DBAnimals", null, 1);
db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();

//Insert some data on the database
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Animals (numberAnimal) " + "VALUES (1)");
```

I was able to get this `DBAnimals` file from `/data/data/...` but it has not got any extension and if I open it with `Notepad ++` it only shows me codified string.

How can I open this `SQLite` database to see the data that I have inserted before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use an app called SQLite Debugger. Look for it in the play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have used [`SQLite Administrator`](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) to import my `SQLite` database and see the data that was inside.

Answer (score 3):

Use a SQLite client. The SQLite project distributes [command-line tools](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) (e.g., `sqlite3`). Other tools can be trivially found using a search engine, searching on `sqlite client`.

Comment: I am sorry but I never had used them. How should I use this commands? Should I download the client on Windows or Android? Thanks for answer :)

Comment: @Error404: If it is a Windows client, you download it on Windows. If it is an OS X client, you download it on OS X. If it is a Linux client, you download it on Linux. If it is a Web browser plugin, you install it through your Web browser. If it is an IDE plugin, you install it through your IDE. In other words, it is computer software. The `sqlite3` command-line interface used to be pre-installed on Android, though IIRC it is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot view the SQLite DB through Notepad.

You can query and check the same way you have inserted:

```
db.execSQL("SELECT * FROM Animals");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SQLite Studio. I have been using it for a couple of years, really nice (free) product.

Copy your DB to a PC and then use SQLite Studio to work with it.

https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use great tool [Stetho](https://facebook.github.io/stetho/) and work with database using Chrome Dev Tools. Add this to your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies { 
  compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2' 
}
```

Then initialize Stetho in custom `Application` class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
  }
}
```

Run you app, launch Chrome and visit this URL `chrome://inspect`. Choose you app with `Inspect` and in left pane find your database.